# Force metabase to show table columns as specified

Tags: format, metabase

I'm using metabase for analytics visualizations with my data being loaded in Google's BigQuery (BQ).

I would like to see the table column names exactly as I specify them in my queries, but metabase was constantly changing them to be "more human readable". So I turned off the `FRIENDLY TABLE AND FIELD NAMES` flag on the admin setting. Disabling the flag removed bunch of unnecessary spaces and change in the case (upper to lower case and vice versa) of some letters, but I still don't see the headers as I specify them.

For example, consider this sample query:

```
#standardSQL
select 2 as num, "hello" as MESSAGE;
```

It shows up properly on BQ.

[image: BQ result]

Note that it kept the word `MESSAGE` in the same case as I had written in the query.

But metabase changes the case on the table columns:

[image: Metabase result]

It changes `MESSAGE` to `Message` and `num` to `Num`. It always only keeps the first letter capitalize.

Is there any way to force metabase to show column names exactly as specified in the queries?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much `metabase` activity here on SO, you might have better luck raising the question here: https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've asked the question on github: https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/7791

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing questions as native queries, write them as follows:

```
select 2 as "num", "hello" as "MESSAGE";
```

You need to put the aliases in quotes. I have done this in Postgres.

You then need to disable "FRIENDLY TABLE AND FIELD NAMES" in the metabase admin.

Comment: This doesn't provide a fix for me. Note that I'm connecting to BigQuery. BQ doesn't allow to wrap column aliases in quotes. Also it's mentioned in the question that the friendly names has been turned off.

Comment: If you are accessing tables and views directly, you will need to check Data model in admin panel, which sometimes already formats the columns and you have to manually modify them. Also, do "Sync database schema" and "Re-scan field values" on the databases after you make changes. But if you are using queries, unfortunately it might be another limitation of metabase.

Comment: @alamoot Bigquery uses backticks ` for quoting similar to MySQL, it does not use double-quote marks like Redshift or Postgres.